# XMPP Framework maximum messages received

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm making a XMPP client and I would like if there is some timer or memory cache for messages received because i send 1000 messages to my client and the server send 1000 messages ok but my client only receive 300.

Possible Solution:
...Overcoming those limits

Every time HTTP has a solution for “fixing” XMPP.

The first two limits can be fixed by running a WebDAV server. Upload to the WebDAV server, share the link. That’s a solution everyone can do without XMPP client support. Of course, having a way to do that transparently with client and server support, with signed URLs (à la S3) would greatly improve the process.

For the connected socket problem, there’s BOSH. That’s basically running XMPP over HTTP. With the added bonus of having the server retaining the “connection” for a couple of minutes – that fixes my iPhone problem. Once I relaunch the client in the two minutes window, all the pending messages are delivered.

Answer (score -1):

Your receiver is receiving only 300 messages means they might be the offline messages. If this is the case you need to increase the Per-user offline message storage limit in your admin panel.

I would like to suggest you to go for message archiving and retrieving instead of depending on offline messages.

Hope this helps you :)